# Magento API Product Create with Dropdown Attributes

Tags: api, magento, attributes, product

I am attempting to load products using the Magento Core API product.create method.

Magento Enterprise 1.10

I am actually having great success with the exception of inserting values for dropdown attributes.  It's my understanding that you simply add the attribute code and it's associated value as part of the "Params" array when you call the product.create method.  I have set up the attributes as dropdowns so they can be included as filter, and I have added the options or "values" before trying to insert the products via the API.  No matter what I do the value is not selected after a successful product upload.

Here are examples of my attempted syntax:

```
'resolution'  => '3000',
'resolution'  => 1,
'resolution'  => array(1),
'resolution'  => array('3000'),
'resolution'  => 3000,
```

Values of YES/NO are accepted for boolean attributes, and I have no problem passing values to regular text fields.  Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Let's make things clearer. Which magento version do you run? You have attribute with attribute code `resolution`, right? Do you insert id of dropdown item or value itself?

Comment: Running Magento Enterprise 1.10.  The attribute name "resolution" is just an example.  I actually have about 50 attributes that are set as dropdown attributes with predetermined values.  I have attempted both methods of inserting the dropdown value iteself, the value position in the dropdown, and the actual ID of the dropdown value - all to no avail.  I have other text field attributes on the products that are recieving their values just fine.  Boolean attributes as well.

Comment: Can you give me an example of how you would pass the values to a dropdown attribute using the Core API?

Comment: Did you see official example http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/doc/webservices-api/api/catalog_product#example_2._product_createviewupdatedelete ? `tax_class_id` is drop-down attribute, `websites` is multiselect.

Comment: Have you tried do it for `tax_class_id`? Does it work? Maybe something is wrong with your custom attribute.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok - so after much trial and error - it appears that you must enter the Attribute Option ID as the value when passing information to dropdown attributes.

You can use the product_attribute.options method along with the attribute ID to get these IDs - or just check your database.

Soo - if attribute 'test-dropdown' has a dropdown option of 'orange' and that option's ID is '220':

'test-dropdown' => 220,

Comment: +1, do you know if you can create those options from API? Or just assign the values?

Comment: Unfortunately - the Magento core API does not allow you to create any attributes.  However - I have implemented the following extension from Netzkollectiv that extends the core API to allow full attribute and attribute set management, as well as the management of configurable products and configurable options for all product types.  http://www.netzkollektiv.com/produkte/magento-extensions/netzkollektiv-api-extension-fur-magento-core-api/

Comment: If you're dealing with custom product attributes, take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/10608275/529403