# Magento SOAP v1 cart_product.add - need to set price in options array for sku

Tags: magento

```
$arrProducts = array(
    array(
        "sku" => "sku1",
        "qty" => 1,
        "options" => array(
            99 => '.50' // 99 is the price attribute id, I want to set this sku to $0.50
        )
    ),
    array(
        "sku" => "sku2",
        "quantity" => 1
    )
);

$resultCartProductAdd = $client->call($session, "cart_product.add", array($shoppingCartId, $arrProducts));
```

In the options array for sku1, how do I set the price to be added to the cart and calculated in totals for checkout?

The above options are not changing the price. The original price for the sku is still being added to the cart instead of $0.50. Looking at [How do I create a product with additional attributes in Magento via Soap/Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8960692) I am still not understanding something.

I am on Magento EE 1.13 using SOAP V1 call

Comment: Looking at the documentation the options value is for product options, so I figure this is going to be for Custom Options on the product rather than attributes like price. My guess is magento will always use the configured product price when adding to the cart via API. How comes it must be different to the normal product price? You may need to use customer groups or tiered pricing to achieve this, or extend the API so it does what you want it to (but I don't think this is that simple due to the way Magento does price calculations), or maybe use vouchers API call to add a coupon to the quote.

Comment: @AshleySwatton where in the documentation do you see the options value is only for custom product options? I guess it would be possible to set the customer group temporarily for this special api call and then set it back after the order is placed, but it seems a little sloppy. I'll have to look into tier pricing. Not sure on that one. I really want to set the price on the fly.

Comment: It doesn't explicitly say custom options, but does say 'An array in the form of option_id => content (optional)'. If it were product attributes it would probably mention attribute_id. Also table catalog_product_option has option_id as the primary key and these tables refer to custom product options. More of an informed guess. Test it out, add a custom option to your product and see. There is no way, even in admin to override a product price when adding to the cart. You could extend the api and pass in price as extra option and maybe try setting the base price on the quote item to it.

Comment: P.S. Magento's API documentation isn't the greatest, it's a lot of trial and learn. There is a good guide on the wiki showing how to extend an existing API function. http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/doc/webservices-api/custom-api. Before the days of customer group pricing, there was only tiered pricing in magento which can be used to effectively do the same thing.

Comment: Tiered pricing won't work for my particular needs here. Changing the group during SOAP checkout temporarily to get the group pricing appears to be the best option without extending the api, if what you're stating is correct. I'm going to research a little more and hope someone else might chime in with some knowledge on changing the SOAP price for sku's. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To set the price on the fly you could extend the API call for adding a product to the cart. The model file Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart_Product_Api would need to be extended and the add method overridden to cater for a price attribute. It would look something like this

```
class Namespace_Module_Model_Cart_Product_Api extends Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart_Product_Api
{
    public function add($quoteId, $productsData, $store=null)
    {
       ...
       $result = $quote->addProduct($productByItem, $productRequest);
       if(isset($productItem['price']) && $productItem['price'] != null) {
           $result->setOriginalCustomPrice($productItem['price']);
       }
       ...
    }
}
```

You could then add price into the array of data in your API call like this.

```
array(
    "sku" => "sku1",
    "qty" => 1,
    "price" => 0.50,
)
```

The add call does issue a collectTotals() call on the quote so it should recalculate tax and currency etc based upon the custom price. You may need to modify the wsdl file to accept the new price attribute. Not tested but in theory should work.

Comment: It is easier to pass this in the options array and then call the following: `$result->setCustomPrice($productItem['options']['price']);
                    $result->setOriginalCustomPrice($productItem['options']['price']);
                    $result->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
                    $result->save();`